# Next button with different distance

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to create a slider with a next button, the images inside my horizontal div are different sizes. I can animate the images with a fixed-width once, I would like to click through the images with one button.  So far I have this:

```js
//function will slide 500px but images are different size so 500px wont work?
$(function() {
  $("a.right").click(function() {
    $(".rolodexSlider").stop().animate({
      left: "-500px",
    }, 500);
    return false;
  });
});
```

```css
<!-- wrapper holds slider -->.rolodexWrapper {
  width: 500px;
  height: 300px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

<!-- slider holds images -->.rolodexSlider {
  height: 300px;
  width: 2000px;
  position: relative;
}

img {
  border: #FF0 solid 1px;
  margin: 10px;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul class="rolodexLetters">
  <li><a href="#" class="left">L</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" class="right">R</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="rolodexWrapper">
  <div class="rolodexSlider">
    <div><img src="" width="250px" height="100px" /></div>
    <div><img src="" width="200px" height="100px" /></div>
    <div><img src="" width="300px" height="100px" /></div>
    <div><img src="" width="275px" height="100px" /></div>
  </div>
</div>​
```

​

Comment: The fastest and easiest way to get answers is to work on the question...

Comment: It's not clear whether you want a way to automagically split the images into pages or just scroll all the way to the last one.

Comment: Ok sorry, i have about 10 images all floating left in a line. I would like to click the next button and the images slide left the width of the image